# Measuring classifier accuracy on word-level

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a list of lists corresponding to sentences of words.

```
X = [
        ['John','has','house'],
        ['Mary','works','at','home']
    ]
```

You can think of each sentence as a training sample. My model, a `tagger`, tags each word with some label:

```
y = [
        ['proper','verb','noun'],
        ['proper','verb','prep','noun']
    ]
```

I would like to grid search my tagger against tagging accuracy on a word level:

```
search = GridSearchCV(tagger, parameters, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
search.fit(X, y)
```

However, `accuracy_score()` method complains that

> {ValueError}You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer transformer can convert to this format.

This does not happen, when list of lists, `y`, is flattened, e.g.:

```
> y_pred = ['proper','verb','noun', 'proper','verb','prep','noun']
> y_true = ['proper','verb','noun', 'proper','verb','prep','noun']
> accuracy_score(y_pred, y_true)
1.0
```

I still want my tagger (Keras model) to predict() a list of list to preserve text structure (sentences, words), but I want scorer to evaluate on word-level.

How can I solve it in an elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I found is to build custom scoring function:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score


def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist ]

def word_accuracy_score(y, y_pred):
    y = flatten(y)
    y_pred = flatten(y_pred)
    return accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
```

and pass it to `GridSearchCV`:

```
scorer = make_scorer(word_accuracy_score)
search = GridSearchCV(tagger, parameters, cv=10, scoring=scorer)
```